# Recommended ways of storing keys on user's machine

Tags: c++, windows, security

I am wondering what are the recommended ways of storing keys on user's machine (windows). This key is used for all sort of encryption and decryption process.

[update]
Things that I found so far :
1) Obfuscate the Hardcoded Key
2) Generate key using MAC , Hardware ID etc

Comment: what have you looked at doing so far?

Comment: what encryption and decryption applications are we talking about?

Answer (score 2):

For storage of key material on a Windows machine, I suggest you look into the [CNG key storage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204778.aspx).

The key storage API allows you to store keys in a protected store, which prevents other processes from reading the key from memory. However, it will not prevent someone from capturing the key at runtime using a debugger.

If you're looking for a licensing / anti-copy system, I suggest you invest in an existing library.

Comment: +1.  Rolling your own cryptography is never a good idea, use the support built into the operating system.